# The meaning of "I would as soon that remain a mystery"

Tags: phrases

So in this [Garfield strip](http://lokalnetz.com/garfield/index.php?date=31.08.1984) I found a sentence that's giving me a hard time fully understanding it. Although the meaning seems to be quite clear from the context, I'm not getting the phrases / expressions used.

In a response to a question whether he'd like to know where eggs come from, Garfield replies "*I would as soon that remain a mystery*". I'm especially not getting the "*as soon*" part: I can imagine the response being e.g. "*I would prefer that remain a mystery*" (or '*remained*' ?).

What am I missing here?

Comment: I think there's a problem with the sentence. I would say there's a missing *as* after *soon*, so the sentence should probably read: *I would as soon as that remain a mystery.*

Comment: What would the meaning be then? Does Garfield want to know where eggs come from, or does he want that to remain a mystery? I'm probably still missing a point here.

Comment: I would (just) as soon = I prefer this over the alternative. I think it should be *remains a mistery* though.

Comment: @Noah, adding an ‘as’ would make the sentence nonsense. ‘As soon’ in this context means ‘just as well’, describing that one does not really have a strong preference one way or the other, but the option mentioned after ‘as soon’ is perhaps slightly better. “That remain” is an elliptical form of “that that remain” (in the subjunctive mood), so the sentence could be recast as: “I would just as gladly have that remain a mystery”, or “I would be equally glad if that remained a mystery”.

Comment: Yes, with the transferred meaning "I would prefer that that remain a mystery" or "I would rather that remain a mystery" - the idiom _is_ slightly non-transparent, as OP suggests.

Comment: I usually see this as _just as soon_, and not just _as soon_. To the O.P.: simply substitute _prefer_ in place of _as soon_, and the meaning should become clear. Garfield could've just as easily said, "I don't want to know."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see nothing whatsoever wrong or difficult about the original sentence:

> I would as soon that remain a mystery.

and I agree completely with OP's rewording as:

> I would *prefer* that remain a mystery.

#### I would *as soon* that remain a mystery.

***as soon as*** (suggested in one comment) is wrong, and is a time-related phrase:

> **as soon as ...** at or not before the moment when ... • *will pay you as soon as I receive the goods* [1](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=soon&title=21st)
>   **as soon as** at the very moment that • *she burst into tears as soon as she saw him* [2](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/soon)

On the other hand, ***as soon ... as ...*** conveys a preference:

> **as soon ... as ...** used to state that the first alternative is slightly preferable to the second • *He'd just as soon die as apologize to her.* [1](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=soon&title=21st)
>   **as soon ... as** used to indicate that the second alternative mentioned is not preferable to the first • *I'd just as soon go by train as drive* [2](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/soon)
>   **soon** readily or willingly: *I would as soon walk as ride.* [3](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/soon)
>   <sub>Note that *most* of the above examples use "*just* as soon ...", but that "*just*" is not part of the defined expression and is optional.</sub>

In the cited sentence, Garfield is using the *first* part of *as soon ... as ...* with the second part being omitted, thus expressing a preference (compared with an unspecified alternative), as in this definition:

> **somebody would (just) as soon** *formal* used to say that someone would prefer to do something or would prefer something to happen: *I'd just as soon you didn't drive the car while I'm gone.* [4](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/soon)

In this sense, the following expressions are all equivalent:

> **(just) as soon ...** : *He'd just as soon die ...* [1](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=soon&title=21st)
>   **(just) as soon ... as** : *I'd just as soon go by train ...* [2](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/soon)
>   **as soon** : *I would as soon walk ...* [3](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/soon)
>   **(just) as soon** : *I'd just as soon you didn't drive the car while I'm gone.* [4](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/soon)
>   **sooner *adverb*** preferably • *I'd sooner die than go back there.* [5](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=sooner&title=21st)
>   **somebody would sooner do something (than)** if you would sooner do something, you would much prefer to do it, especially instead of something that seems unpleasant: *I'd sooner die than marry you!* [4](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/soon)
>   **sooner *adv.*** With willingness; readily: *I'd as soon leave right now.* [3](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/soon)

#### I would as soon *that* remain a mystery.

As stated in another comment, the first *that* is omitted, as in:

> I would as soon [that] *that* remain a mystery.
>   I would as soon [that] *it* remain a mystery.

#### I would as soon that *remain* a mystery.

A further comment suggested that *remains* should have been used instead of *remain*, but the subjunctive form *remain* is correct.

So, when Garfield said:

> I would as soon that remain a mystery.

he meant

> I would very much prefer that where eggs come from should continue to be a mystery to me.

But he is known for his brevity - and it would have been more difficult to fit a longer form in the speech bubble!

Comment: *the fist* should be first. Excellent answer too! I think you ought to re-Christen yourself, Chambers from now on :)

Comment: Corrected. And thanks. *Chambers* is my first dictionary of choice! One copy still in use was bought in 1974, but I find I have a *Pocket Oxford Dict.* "reprinted 1959"; & a copy of Partridge's *Usage & Abusage* priced *9/-* (i.e. *9 shillings* - pre-1971). In this answer, I did in fact use 5-6 different dictionaries!

Comment: +1. Very thorough answer, though I think the “very much” bit in the final expanded version is slightly misleading—to me at least, ‘just as soon’ indicates only a _vague_ preference, rather than a strong one. (Differing here from ‘sooner’, which feels much stronger)

Comment: Thanks for such a thorough answer! Especially the examples with 'sooner' helped me somehow get the sense of the expression. Wasn't aware of its existence at all.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks. Must admit that the 'expanded' version was really a bit of hyperbole! I've never though of there being a difference in emphasis between '(just) as soon' and 'sooner'; none was indicated in any of the references I looked at.