# I would as soon do X as do Y

Tags: phrase-meaning

I thought "I would as soon do X as do Y" means "I would rather do X than do Y," as in "I would as soon die at once as live in this agony." But in the following quote it seems to be the other way around: "I would rather do Y than do X."

> La Bruyère said: 'Women often love liberty only to abuse it.' Two
> hundred years later Balzac wrote: 'There are women who crave for
> liberty in order to make bad use of it.' The thoughts are not great,
> they are not even true, but that is not the question. Could such a
> genius as Balzac be accused of plagiarism because he expressed a
> thought practically in the very words of La Bruyère? I would as soon
> charge Balzac with plagiarism as I would accuse a Vanderbilt or a
> Carnegie of trying to cheat a street-car conductor out of a penny
> fare.
>
> (Max O'Rell, *Rambles in Womanland*)

The author is saying that Balzac is NOT a plagiarist, isn't he? Am I misreading the passage? I appreciate it very much if you give me some clarification.

Comment: Answered on ELL at [I'd just as soon ...](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8841/id-just-as-soon-as-to). '
It can also be used to indicate that both options are negative, for example:

• "Would you like to go to a party?"
... • "I'd just as soon be eaten by wolves!" ' {Richard Williams}

Comment: The "as ... as" construction is underdetermined. "I am as tall as John" can mean that I am at least as tall as John (i.e. possibly taller), or it can mean that we are *the same height*. It can be used both ways. The meaning you identify is based on X being "at least" as desirable as Y, in other words X probably being preferable. But in the passage you quote from, the meaning is that X and Y are equally desirable/likely, which in each case is not much!

Answer (score 1):

#### Equally undesirable?

[This answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/123053) gives a usage of "as soon" where "as soon X as Y" means that "the second alternative mentioned is not preferable to the first". This is consistent with the alternatives being equally preferable.

In the example quoted by the OP, one of the alternatives is something the speaker is clearly *not* willing to do, so the speaker implies that they are not willing to do the other one either.

#### Confusion of two idioms?

Where the writer's point is that Y is undesirable, and they use an obviously undesirable X to make that point, the usual order, as the OP points out, is "I'd as soon do X as do Y". There's also the idiom "I'd no more do Y than do X". Perhaps this writer confused the two idioms.

Answer (score 0):

The use of "I would as soon do X as do Y" is rhetorical.

"Do X" is chosen as something that is unbelievable, that cannot be realized, or appears so anyway, and in saying that it is preferable to do X the speaker emphasizes that there is virtually no chance of doing Y, as by comparison there is an even greater difficulty (since "doing X" is preferable as regards difficulty). So what is unbelievable or difficult is to accuse people  as wealthy as a Vanderbilt or a Carnegie to try to cheat someone of a few pennies; this shows that "doing X" and "doing Y" have been reversed.

- I would as soon accuse a Vanderbilt or a Carnegie of trying to cheat a street-car conductor out of a penny fare as I would charge Balzac with plagiarism.